# Refresh "Time function"

Tags: javascript, function, react-native

My function is supposed to switch when she is working. Basically , it's 11pm , she is supposed to switch if it's 11:01pm but i have to reload the app to make it work. Do you know how to switch the function without reload all the app ?

```
startMatchOrStop = () => {
    return this.state.sport.clubs.map((element) => {
      var dateMatch = new Date(element.dateMatch).getTime();

      var dateMatchStop = new Date(element.dateMatchStop).getTime();
      var today = Date.now();
      console.log(dateMatch);
      console.log(dateMatchStop);
      console.log(today);

      if (today >= dateMatch && today < dateMatchStop) {
        return (
          this.setState({soundCapture: true}),
          RNSoundLevel.start(),
          (RNSoundLevel.onNewFrame = (data) => {
            this.setState({soundArray: data.value});
            this.PostDecibels();
            console.log(today >= dateMatchStop);
          })
        );
      } else {
        return (
          console.log(today <= dateMatchStop),
          RNSoundLevel.stop(),
          this.setState({soundCapture: false}),
          Alert.alert('Titre', 'Match Fini enregistrement terminé')
        );
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: what do you mean with "switch the function"

Comment: @luke, i want the "else" instead of the "if " without to reload the app

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function to re-run again

you may put it inside interval
and check it every X seconds for Y time(s).

for example:

```
var retryCount = 3; 
var startFuncInt = setInterval(() => {    
     if (--retry){
         startMatchOrStop();    
     } 
     else{
        window.clearInterval(startFuncInt);
     }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you ! where should i put the interval exactly ?

Comment: put it in some init() function or instead of where you used to call startMatchOrStop()

Comment: A little bit yes :D still a problem with this function but we work on it ! thank for your help